# What is the difference in usage of "in" and "off" in this context?

Tags: difference, usage

The following sentences are in relation with cricket. In TV, it shows:

> They need 25 runs off 30 balls.

But I wonder, however, that what would be the difference if I spell something like:

> They need 25 runs in 30 balls.

Are these both acting like synonyms?

Comment: Cricket has its own way of saying perfectly ordinary things in peculiar ways, perhaps to deliberately confuse Americans unfamiliar with the sport.  As with most sports *lingo* I would just copy what is commonly said and not worry about the grammar of it.  :)

Comment: Both ok, you could also say 25 runs from 30 balls, or even 25 runs in the last 5 overs.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Andrew. Just stick with the way it's most commonly said. In this case, I think it makes more sense saying "off", versus "in" as saying "in" makes me think of a "place" rather than the object. If you're interested in more sports and cricket lingo, there's this [site](https://www.sportslingo.com/) that can help.